# How to find out execution time of sqlite query?

Tags: java, sql, sqlite, database-performance

**First thing:
Please read the question details before marking this as a duplicate.**

I am using sqlite db with JAVA. Here's what I have **already** tried:

1. I have tracked query times using start and end time from within JAVA code. But I want more accurate data.
2. I have also tracked time using sqlite browser. But in sqlite browser, total time i.e. time to fetch data + time to plot data comes.
3. I have also tried to track time using sqlite command line (.timer ON), but I get comparatively higher time values in all 3 heads: real, user, sys.

I want only the time that it takes to find and fetch data.

How can I find out the fetch time? I have to make a decision based on the **actual time values**, whether it will be beneficial for us to use sqlite db.

**EDIT: How can I debug the query to know which part of query is taking how much time?**

Comment: What is the precision of your Java timestamps? Don't you get nanoseconds?

Comment: @CL. I have used nanoseconds. I just wanted to make sure that calculating time in nanoseconds from inside Java code, is the closest I can get to determining actual query time?

Comment: How could it not be closest? Do you want more precision? Or do you think that it measures something that you do not want to measure? And if you think that there might be a problem with your measuring code, *show that code*.

Comment: @CL. It's just that I am not sure whether the tie calculated through Java Code adds some additional time taken by JDBC driver.

Comment: Execute and measure `SELECT 0;`, then you know all the overhead without the actual database access.

Comment: Thanks CL. This will help. Also, is there a way to debug which part of query is taking how much time. I have tried "Explain Query Plan" but it does not show any time breakdown.